# Why radio station KBHR in Northern Exposure is pronounced K-Bear

Tags: nothern-exposure

Why is the radio station KBHR in Northern Exposure pronounced K-Bear (bear like Yogi Bear)? The only explanation I've found is in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KBHR):

> KBHR were also the call letters of the 570AM radio station in the fictitious town of Cicely, Alaska, on the CBS television dramedy Northern Exposure.

Comment: Glad someone else still watches NE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's common for radio stations to try to make their call letters into "pronounceable" words, because it's good marketing. A random string of letters is harder to remember than a word, especially if that word has some relevant to what the station is playing. Since the "K" is a standard first letter for a radio call-sign (in the Western US), stations usually try to use the other three letters to make the word.

The station is broadcasting from Alaska, and one of the things associate with Alaska are polar bears.

So, by trying to read out "BHR" at a word, they came up with "bear".

Comment: Isn't Alaska rather associated with grizzlies, not polar bears?

Comment: If you live in Alaska then yes; it you live in the lower 48 watching watching a show about Alaska, it's probably a toss up. K-BEAR works either way :)